# Can you define an AJAX request without making the request in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

With jQuery you can make an ajax request like this:

```
request=$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
});

request.success(function(){
    alert('Yay!');
});
```

However, let's say I didn't want immediately make the ajax request.  I just wanted to define it and bind it to an event.  Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Why won't you write the ajax in that event?

Comment: Are you sure this success callback will be fired that way?!

Comment: @gdoron So I can use it a couple times and I think it is slightly neater to write it out first and then call it.

The answer to your second question is yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would this suit your need?

```
function callMeLater() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "test.html",
    });
}

//and later

$(selector).anyevent(function() {
    callMeLater();
});
```

Comment: i use this method allot you can even expand on it t put in different parameters by passing an object through the callMeLater function

Answer (score 3):

```
$("#but").click(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "test.html",
    success: function(){
      //...
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure why you would do this but you could do something like this:

```
var ajaxParams = {
   cache: false,
   success: function(){...
}

$("something").click(function(){
    $.ajax(ajaxParams);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, sure.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#somebutton').bind('click',function(){
    $.ajax({
      url: "test.html"
    });
  });
});
```